# Getting hold of Amazon Fiona (Kindle) CSRF token

Tags: csrf, reverse-engineering, kindle

Amazon has an [administration page for content sent to your Kindle](https://www.amazon.com/gp/digital/fiona/manage). This page uses an undocumented HTTP API that sends requests like this:

```
{
  "csrfToken":"gEABCzVR2QsRk3F2QVkLcdKuQzYCPcpGkFNte0SAAAAAJAAAAAFkUgW5yYXcAAAAA",
  "data":{"param":{"DeleteContent":{"asinDetails":{"3RSCWFGCUIZ3LD2EEROJUI6M5X63RAE2":{"category":"KindlePDoc"},"375SVWE22FINQY3FZNGIIDRBZISBGJTD":{"category":"KindlePDoc"},"4KMPV2CIWUACT4QHQPETLHCVTWEJIM4N":{"category":"KindlePDoc"}}}}}
}
```

I made a [wrapper library](https://github.com/fatso83/amazon_fiona_js) for the previous API they used, but this time they have added CSRF tokens, making each session unique. That is a bit of a show stopper, and I was wondering how I can get hold of these tokens. I did not find it in the cookies. This is for use in a Chrome Extension, so issues like CORS is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, after manually going searching the Response tab of each request in the "XHR" and "Doc" tab, I was able to find out that this token is set in an inline script in the `myx.html` (main page):

```
var csrfToken = "gPNABCIemSqEWBeXae3l1CqMPESRa4bXBq0W7rCIAAAAJAAAAAFkUlo1yYXcAAAAA";
```

This means it is set on the `window` object, making it available for all there. I guess this means a Chrome extension would need to fetch this page and manually parse the html to retrieve this token. Sad, but doable, although highly fragile :-(